# PowerShell Not Starting

Tags: windows, powershell

For some reason, PowerShell no longer opens on my computers.  Opening PowerShell displays the following but never finishes opening and never displays a prompt:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6
```

PowerShell was working fine yesterday, and I did not install any new programs or any Windows updates.  Has anyone else experienced this and been able to fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: [1] what happens if you start with `-NoProfile`? [2] do you see anything showing up in your event logs?

Comment: Thank you for your response and your suggestions.  Running `powershell.exe -NoProfile` did not fix the issue.  I looked at the Event Viewer on another computer that does not have this issue, and running PowerShell seems to generate three events:

1) `PowerShell console is starting up`
2) `Windows PowerShell has started an IPC listening thread on process: 18152 in AppDomain: DefaultAppDomain`
3) `PowerShell console is ready for user input`

On the computer in which the issue does occur, the third event never runs.

Comment: What happened between yesterday and today? A major Windows update? Installed new software? I think you'd better restore the computer to a point in time before yesterday

Comment: @ChristopherLorr - you are welcome! [*grin*] ///// what is the date on your most recent restore point? if it is from today or yesterday ... then something triggered it - likely an update or install.

Comment: Hi, I had this issue (powershell not starting up) and while rebooting the machine the System Event Log Service did not stop. It might be that this (Event service being unresponsive) might also be the root cause of powershell not starting. After rebooting (had to reset the machine) powershell worked again.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me a few days ago, and while I didn't run with `NoProfile`, I ended up clearning the profile and modules in use from my user profile. After I did that, Windows Terminal began working again. I restored my custom profiles and the problem did not return.